# FreeNAS share for multiple clients

Tags: truenas

I'm setting up a freenas box. I need both windows and mac machines to access the volume. The documentation says not to set up 2 shares (cifs and afp) but i'm having problems figuring out how to share files another way. I can not create 2 datasets because I need the files to be shared. Is it ok for me to use 2 shares? If not, what are my other options?

-thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Most OSX instances I've run across can also access CIFS shares pretty simply, which would allow you to only create one, and avoid the permissions problems ErikA alluded to. The command-sequence would be <kbd>command</kbd> <kbd>K</kbd>, and `smb://servername-or-ip/share/` in the finder bar.

Comment: This seems like a simple solution, but the documentation hints that there are performance issue that may occur with this setup. but ... "it is slower than an NFS share due to the single-threaded design of Samba" only hints that its slower then NFS, do you know how it compares to AFP?

Comment: @mike Not a lot of experience. The last I used the *nix AFP stack was netAtalk which kind of sucked, samba was *much* better back then. I think things have gotten better, but I don't know by how much.

Comment: @mike: yes, a samba server will usually be slower than an NFS server running on the same hardware, but you're not running samba on your Mac clients - it's on the freenas box (where it needs to be running already for the mswindows clients.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, just create two shares. Keep in mind that when sharing via two or more methods, permissions may get wonky depending on how you have things set up.